# How to assign custom series label?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am currently using nvd3 for my project. And I have a mult-Bar-Horizontal-Chart. I have multiple series with different units, such as seconds. I would like to have  values shown with their unit. For example, in the example http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarHorizontalChart, I would like to have the first positive value "25.31" displayed with "25.31 second". I have tried using valueFormat option, but it seems to apply the function to all series. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For such customisations, I would suggest you to extend multiBarHorizontalChart chart type to create a custom chart type. Edit this function to add code where you can pass a unit to the valueFormatter function. I have done many such customisations with nvd3 in past.

Comment: Do you know where can I find the information to create a custom chart through ng2-nvd3?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. In my case, I had forked the library and edited the source code creating a new function. You could do something similar.